# The Sylow-p subgroups contains all the elements of order p?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

If $G$ is a group of order $35=7\cdot5$ and $n_7$ is the number of the Sylow 7-subgroups then there are just $n_7\cdot 6$ elements of order 7?

Answer:
Yes because
If not suppose there  exist $g$ with order 7 then $\langle g\rangle$ has order 7  and it is a subgroup of G then it must be Sylow 7-subrgoup

Am I right?
This holds in general for an element of order p and sylow-p subgroups?

Comment: $n_7\cdot 6$ elements such that what?

Comment: I assume you mean $n_7\cdot 6$ elements of order $7$?

Comment: yes elements of order 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete your argument you need to show that if $a,b$ both have order $7$ and $a^i=b^j\neq e$, for some integers $i,j$ then $\langle a\rangle= \langle b\rangle$.

That is you need to show that distinct Sylow $7$-subgroups do not intersect non-trivially (the intersection is just $\{e\}$).  This should be an easy exercise in modular arithmetic.

To answer your last question note that sometimes distinct Sylow subgroups intersect non-trivially.

Consider the symmetry group of a hexagon.  This has a Sylow $2$-subgroup for each pair of orthogonal reflections, consisting of the reflections, the identity and a $180^\circ$ rotation.

[image]

Here there are $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, each containing $3$ elements of order $2$, but only $7$ elements of order $2$ in total.